ROUND_HALF_DOWN in informix
i tried the round with mode syntax but it's giving me an error in informix (3.50).
Can you help me please or give me other alternative if mode is not supported in this version?

Thank you in advance

The syntax for the Informix ROUND function does not include the MODE ROUND_HALF_DOWN syntax.  Attempts to use it, therefore, will fail.

AH ok, any idea please how can i round for example 2.657 to 2.66 and 2.655 with 2.65? as it's done with ROUND_HALF_DOWN?

@salma , as a workaround you can substract a small amount from number:  round(3.565 - 0.000001, 2)
